# One of three blades on lawn mower very loose and spinning freely

Tags: repair, lawn-mower

When I turned the blades on on my Snapper Pro, the whole mower shook and made a lot of noise.  Upon inspection, one of the blades appears to be free-spinning instead of connected to the belt.

As you can see in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-63i1Ph4gY), the blade is wobbly and spins freely.  When I try to move the other blades, they don't move, but I can see the belt wiggle, showing that they're connected.

My first guess is that I need to somehow tighten that bolt under the blade, but upon inspection, it doesn't seem loose at all. I haven't taken a wrench to it yet, but I assumed if it was loose enough to allow that much play in the blade, that it would be loose to the touch too.

Thoughts on what I should do or try?

[Here's another video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCIsRVtkEf8) of me fiddling around with it and showing that when I attempt to spin a different blade, it does wiggle the bolt and housing above and below the loose blade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was eventually able to get the right sized wrench 15/16th, and was able to back off the bolt holding on the blade, then cleaned it up, and put it back on.  I had to put a block (2x4 chunk) to keep the other blades from spinning as I tightened it, but eventually got it tight enough that all seems to be back in working condition.

I'm still confused how it could get so loose so fast without hitting something, and also, if it was that loose, why was the bolt so darn tight.  But alas, it was just the bolt that needed tightened.  Problem solved.

Comment: On my lawn tractor the blade has 5 or 6 lobes that match the shaft. My son sharpened the blades and got lucky with 2 but the 3rd he had the blade on top of the lobes and he had really cranked it down. I had the same problem with removing the bolt as you had but when the blade was in the correct position it held and worked fine. (Other than the lobes being slightly smashed).

Answer (score 0):

your blade is likely out of balance and needs to be resharpened and balanced. Also a dab of blue loctite is very helpful in insuring they retaining nut or bolt stays tight.